# if else statement inside array (shorthand version still doesn't work) php

Tags: php

I had no idea it was not possible to use if else statement inside an array in php. I've searched stackoverflow and found that shorthand version should actually work fine.

I tried it but still have errors and page doesn't load, my code:

```
query_posts (array(

                                ($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' ? "'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc'," : "")

                                'order' => 'DESC',
                                'orderby' => $prefooter_order_logic,

                                'posts_per_page' => '10',
                                'post_type' => 'post',
                                'category_name' => $prefooter_category_select

                            ));
```

This doesn't give me error:

but it doesn't work...

```
($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' ? "

                                    'v_sortby' => 'views',
                                    'v_orderby' => 'desc',

                                    " : "

                                    'order' => 'DESC',
                                    'orderby' => $prefooter_order_logic,

                                    "),
```

I've decided to stop playing around and do it easiest way:

btw, any thoughts if this is the best way to do it? or not?

```
                if ($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews') {

                    query_posts (array(
                        'v_sortby' => 'views',
                        'v_orderby' => 'desc',
                        'posts_per_page' => '10',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => $prefooter_category_select
                    ));

                } else {

                    query_posts (array(
                        'order' => 'DESC',
                        'orderby' => $prefooter_order_logic,
                        'posts_per_page' => '10',
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => $prefooter_category_select
                    ));

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will produce `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` because you are missing a comma at the end of this line:

```
($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' ? "'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc'," : ""), 
                                                                                           ^ here
```

Edit:

Just modify the array after creating it, based on your condition:

```
$arr = array(

    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $prefooter_category_select

);

if($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews')
{
    $arr['v_sortby'] = 'views';
    $arr['v_orderby'] = 'desc';
}
else
{
    $arr['order'] = 'DESC';
    $arr['orderby'] = $prefooter_order_logic;
}

query_posts($arr);
```

Alternatively, use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$arr = array(

    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => $prefooter_category_select

);

$arr = $prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' ? array_merge($arr, array('v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc')) : array_merge($arr, array('order' => 'desc', 'orderby' => $prefooter_order_logic));

query_posts($arr);
```

Comment: You were right, it was comma at the end. But now none of my array variables are read. I also have to place $ variable inside else part... I updated my question with new code, can you take a look.

Comment: what if I move whole query under if? if == xviews -> query 1, else query 2. And finish playing around with things I don't know :D

Comment: @SandroDzneladze yes you can put the whole query under the if else but that will be duplicating code.

Comment: Readability of if else is better yes, only if you don't duplicate the whole query under both outcomes.

Answer (score 2):

here is the problem first that there is not `)` after the `?`   and `,` at teh end

```
$prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' ? "'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc'," : "")
```

should be

```
($prefooter_order_logic == 'xviews' )? "'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc'," : ""),
```

Comment: `here is the problem first that there is not ) after the ?` - that has nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should specify what errors you have, and it's hard to tell what you are trying to do.

However, you are missing a comma at the end of the line with the ternary operator:

```
'desc'," : "")
```

Put a comma after that.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you couldn't evaluate PHP code like this:

```
"'v_sortby' => 'views', 'v_orderby' => 'desc',"
```

It should looks like piece of text for PHP interpreter, not part of your array, but I'm not sure.